# DatePicker UI-Kitten Invariant Violation

Tags: javascript, react-native, expo, react-native-ui-kitten

tried to fix this issue here, but I don't understand what could be causing it...

I was using the Calendar component in my project with no issues. However, I decided it would be more convenient replacing it by the DatePicker, which apparently uses pretty much the same. Here is the code I have so far (relevant part):

```
import React from 'react'; 
import {   
            Alert,
            ScrollView, 
            StyleSheet, 
            View, 
            InteractionManager, 
            Image, 
            TextInput, 
            TouchableOpacity, 
            BackHandler 


        } from 'react-native';

import {
  Card,
  CardHeader,
  Layout,
  Text,
  Calendar,
  DatePicker,
  Spinner,
} from '@ui-kitten/components';

import { TaskCard } from './components/task-card';


import { validate } from 'validate.js';

import { Auth, Storage, API, graphqlOperation, scTracker } from '../modules/commons'; 
import Styles from '../modules/styles';
import constraints from './fields/constraints';


import Ionicons from 'react-native-vector-icons/Ionicons';

import { CustomCalendar } from './components/custom-calendar';


class TasksScreen extends React.Component {
    static navigationOptions = { 
        title: "Atividades",     
    };

    state = {
      cDate: null,
      showCalendar: false,
    };

    constructor(props) { 
        super(props);

    };

    componentDidMount() {
        try {
            let lcDate = new Date();
            this.setState({
                cDate: lcDate,
            });
        } catch (e) {
            console.log(e);
        };
    };

    render() {
        return(

. . . . . 

                    <Layout level="2" style={{width:"100%"}}>

                        <DatePicker     date={this.state.cDate}
                                        onSelect={(date)=>{this.setState({cDate: date})}} 
                        />

                    </Layout>


                    <ScrollView contentContainerStyle={Styles.vScrollViewContent}>

                        <TaskCard

. . . . . .
```

But for some reason, with exactly the same parameters, it started to trigger an error pointing exactly on the line of the Layout wrapping the date picker (alog with all other Layout objects):

```
Warning: React.createElement: type is invalid -- expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: %s.%s%s, undefined,  You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports.

Check your code at tasks-scr.js:91., 
    in TasksScreen (at SceneView.js:9)
    in SceneView (at createTabNavigator.tsx:67)
    in RCTView (at View.js:45)
    in View (at SceneView.tsx:92)
    in SceneView (at TabView.tsx:173)
    in RCTView (at View.js:45)
    in View (at createAnimatedComponent.js:217)
    in AnimatedComponent (at Pager.tsx:667)
    in PanGestureHandler (at Pager.tsx:659)
    in Pager (at TabView.tsx:70)
    in RCTView (at View.js:45)
    in View (at TabView.tsx:128)
    in TabView (at createMaterialTopTabNavigator.tsx:136)
    in MaterialTabView (at createTabNavigator.tsx:228)
    in NavigationView (at createNavigator.js:80)
    in Navigator (at SceneView.js:9)
    in SceneView (at StackViewLayout.tsx:889)
    in RCTView (at View.js:45)
    in View (at StackViewLayout.tsx:888)
    in RCTView (at View.js:45)
    in View (at StackViewLayout.tsx:887)
    in RCTView (at View.js:45)
    in View (at createAnimatedComponent.js:151)
    in AnimatedComponent (at StackViewCard.tsx:106)
    in RCTView (at View.js:45)
    in View (at createAnimatedComponent.js:151)
    in AnimatedComponent (at screens.native.js:71)
    in Screen (at StackViewCard.tsx:93)
    in Card (at createPointerEventsContainer.tsx:95)
    in Container (at StackViewLayout.tsx:975)
    in RCTView (at View.js:45)
    in View (at screens.native.js:101)
    in ScreenContainer (at StackViewLayout.tsx:384)
    in RCTView (at View.js:45)
    in View (at createAnimatedComponent.js:151)
    in AnimatedComponent (at StackViewLayout.tsx:374)
    in PanGestureHandler (at StackViewLayout.tsx:367)
    in StackViewLayout (at withOrientation.js:30)
    in withOrientation (at StackView.tsx:104)
    in RCTView (at View.js:45)
    in View (at Transitioner.tsx:267)
    in Transitioner (at StackView.tsx:41)
    in StackView (at createNavigator.js:80)
    in Navigator (at createKeyboardAwareNavigator.js:12)
    in KeyboardAwareNavigator (at SceneView.js:9)
    in SceneView (at StackViewLayout.tsx:889)
    in RCTView (at View.js:45)
    in View (at StackViewLayout.tsx:888)
    in RCTView (at View.js:45)
    in View (at StackViewLayout.tsx:887)
    in RCTView (at View.js:45)
    in View (at createAnimatedComponent.js:151)
    in AnimatedComponent (at StackViewCard.tsx:106)
    in RCTView (at View.js:45)
    in View (at createAnimatedComponent.js:151)
    in AnimatedComponent (at screens.native.js:71)
    in Screen (at StackViewCard.tsx:93)
    in Card (at createPointerEventsContainer.tsx:95)
    in Container (at StackViewLayout.tsx:975)
    in RCTView (at View.js:45)
    in View (at screens.native.js:101)
    in ScreenContainer (at StackViewLayout.tsx:384)
    in RCTView (at View.js:45)
    in View (at createAnimatedComponent.js:151)
    in AnimatedComponent (at StackViewLayout.tsx:374)
    in PanGestureHandler (at StackViewLayout.tsx:367)
    in StackViewLayout (at withOrientation.js:30)
    in withOrientation (at StackView.tsx:104)
    in RCTView (at View.js:45)
    in View (at Transitioner.tsx:267)
    in Transitioner (at StackView.tsx:41)
    in StackView (at createNavigator.js:80)
    in Navigator (at createKeyboardAwareNavigator.js:12)
    in KeyboardAwareNavigator (at createAppContainer.js:430)
    in NavigationContainer (at App.js:21)
    in RCTView (at View.js:45)
    in View (at modalPanel.component.js:62)
    in ModalPanel (at applicationProvider.component.js:68)
    in ThemeProvider (at styleProvider.component.js:13)
    in MappingProvider (at styleProvider.component.js:12)
    in StyleProvider (at applicationProvider.component.js:67)
    in ApplicationProvider (at App.js:19)
    in App (at withExpoRoot.js:20)
    in RootErrorBoundary (at withExpoRoot.js:19)
    in ExpoRootComponent (at renderApplication.js:35)
    in RCTView (at View.js:45)
    in View (at AppContainer.js:98)
    in RCTView (at View.js:45)
    in View (at AppContainer.js:115)
    in AppContainer (at renderApplication.js:34)
- node_modules/expo/build/environment/muteWarnings.fx.js:27:24 in error
- node_modules/react/cjs/react.development.js:188:36 in warningWithoutStack
- node_modules/react/cjs/react.development.js:603:32 in warning
- node_modules/react/cjs/react.development.js:1730:14 in createElementWithValidation
* src/screens/tasks-scr.js:91:25 in render
- node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Renderer/oss/ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:11581:21 in finishClassComponent
- node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Renderer/oss/ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:11509:4 in updateClassComponent
- ... 15 more stack frames from framework internals

Invariant Violation: Invariant Violation: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports.

Check the render method of `TasksScreen`.
- node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Renderer/oss/ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:5716:10 in createFiberFromTypeAndProps
- node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Renderer/oss/ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:5744:4 in createFiberFromElement
- ... 19 more stack frames from framework internals

Warning: Can't perform a React state update on an unmounted component. This is a no-op, but it indicates a memory leak in your application. To fix, cancel all subscriptions and asynchronous tasks in %s.%s, the componentWillUnmount method, 
    in TabBar (at MaterialTopTabBar.tsx:92)
    in TabBarTop (at createMaterialTopTabNavigator.tsx:84)
    in Pager (at TabView.tsx:70)
    in RCTView (at View.js:45)
    in View (at TabView.tsx:128)
    in TabView (at createMaterialTopTabNavigator.tsx:136)
    in MaterialTabView (at createTabNavigator.tsx:228)
    in NavigationView (at createNavigator.js:80)
    in Navigator (at SceneView.js:9)
    in SceneView (at StackViewLayout.tsx:889)
    in RCTView (at View.js:45)
    in View (at StackViewLayout.tsx:888)
    in RCTView (at View.js:45)
    in View (at StackViewLayout.tsx:887)
    in RCTView (at View.js:45)
    in View (at createAnimatedComponent.js:151)
    in AnimatedComponent (at StackViewCard.tsx:106)
    in RCTView (at View.js:45)
    in View (at createAnimatedComponent.js:151)
    in AnimatedComponent (at screens.native.js:71)
    in Screen (at StackViewCard.tsx:93)
    in Card (at createPointerEventsContainer.tsx:95)
    in Container (at StackViewLayout.tsx:975)
    in RCTView (at View.js:45)
    in View (at screens.native.js:101)
    in ScreenContainer (at StackViewLayout.tsx:384)
    in RCTView (at View.js:45)
    in View (at createAnimatedComponent.js:151)
    in AnimatedComponent (at StackViewLayout.tsx:374)
    in PanGestureHandler (at StackViewLayout.tsx:367)
    in StackViewLayout (at withOrientation.js:30)
    in withOrientation (at StackView.tsx:104)
    in RCTView (at View.js:45)
    in View (at Transitioner.tsx:267)
    in Transitioner (at StackView.tsx:41)
    in StackView (at createNavigator.js:80)
    in Navigator (at createKeyboardAwareNavigator.js:12)
    in KeyboardAwareNavigator (at SceneView.js:9)
    in SceneView (at StackViewLayout.tsx:889)
    in RCTView (at View.js:45)
    in View (at StackViewLayout.tsx:888)
    in RCTView (at View.js:45)
    in View (at StackViewLayout.tsx:887)
    in RCTView (at View.js:45)
    in View (at createAnimatedComponent.js:151)
    in AnimatedComponent (at StackViewCard.tsx:106)
    in RCTView (at View.js:45)
    in View (at createAnimatedComponent.js:151)
    in AnimatedComponent (at screens.native.js:71)
    in Screen (at StackViewCard.tsx:93)
    in Card (at createPointerEventsContainer.tsx:95)
    in Container (at StackViewLayout.tsx:975)
    in RCTView (at View.js:45)
    in View (at screens.native.js:101)
    in ScreenContainer (at StackViewLayout.tsx:384)
    in RCTView (at View.js:45)
    in View (at createAnimatedComponent.js:151)
    in AnimatedComponent (at StackViewLayout.tsx:374)
    in PanGestureHandler (at StackViewLayout.tsx:367)
    in StackViewLayout (at withOrientation.js:30)
    in withOrientation (at StackView.tsx:104)
    in RCTView (at View.js:45)
    in View (at Transitioner.tsx:267)
    in Transitioner (at StackView.tsx:41)
    in StackView (at createNavigator.js:80)
    in Navigator (at createKeyboardAwareNavigator.js:12)
    in KeyboardAwareNavigator (at createAppContainIjs:430)
- node_modules/expo/build/environment/muteWarnings.fx.js:27:24 in error
```

Thanks in advance folks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no `DatePicker` component in this library. However, there is `Datepicker`